# How to import cx_Oracle library into python SikuliX script

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle, sikuli-x

I'm trying to import `cx_Oracle` library into my Python test script inside `sikulix`, however I'm getting this error:

> [error] script [ connect_and_print ] stopped with error at line --unknown--
>       [error] Error caused by: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\BRX Retail\Desktop\Testes_automatic\connect_and_print.sikuli\connect_and_print.py", line 3, in  import cx_Oracle ImportError: No module named cx_Oracle

This is my code:

```
import random
import org.sikuli.script.SikulixForJython
import cx_Oracle
```

Do you guys have some ideas?

Comment: Just for Knowledge I solve my problem with this: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/678478

Answer (score 0):

`cx_Oracle` cannot be imported to SikuliX: it is C-based and depends on native libs.

SikuliX internally use Jython as interpreter, which is Java based and can only import Python modules, that are written in plain Python (no C-based stuff).

As Antonio mentioned: some possible workarounds might be derived from [As Antonio mentioned: some possible workarounds might be derived from here](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/678478)